# Why is "it" wrong in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns

From the SAT:

> When Doris Lessing published The Golden Notebook in 1962, **it** instantly established herself as one of the most important literary voices of her generation.

It said that **it** is wrong. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: *she instantly established herself.*

Comment: OR *it instantly established her*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflexive pronoun has to echo the head.

> **Examples:**
>   I kidded myself; you enjoyed yourself; she established
>   herself;

If you had written " **It** established **itself...** " It would be good grammar, but it would mean that the book became a classic which is different from saying Doris Lessing established her reputation.

Comment: If it was "it instantly established her" would it be right?

Comment: @dngr193 Sorry, I misread your comment.  Yes, just as good. **It** stands for the publication event.